# DJANGO: Allow white spaces on username? regex not working?

Tags: django, regex, python-2.7, django-users

I am using

```
 django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to create a user (not extending user) and I want to enable whitespaces on usernames. I've tried the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.validators import ASCIIUsernameValidator

class MyValidator(ASCIIUsernameValidator):
    regex = r'^[\w.@+-\s]+$'


class MyUser(User):
    username_validator = MyValidator

    class Meta:
        proxy = True  # If no new field is added.


# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    # Venue Name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

ISSUE: It's not accepting white spaces. Throw form error: `"Enter a valid username. This value may contain only English letters, numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters."`

ideas?

Django=1.11.29

Comment: `r'^[\w.@+-\s]+$'` => `r'^[\w\s.@+-]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

username_validator = MyValidator

to

username_validator = MyValidator()

check this out:
[How to customize username validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030567/how-to-customize-username-validation)